# Draw nearest value from sorted data frame into unsorted data frame

Tags: r, matching, cumulative-frequency

I have two data frames in `R`. The first data frame is a cumulative frequency distribution (`cumFreqDist`) with associated periods. The first rows of the data frame look like this:

```
Time        cumfreq
0         0.0000000
4         0.9009009
6         1.8018018
8         7.5075075
12       23.4234234
16       39.6396396
18       53.4534535
20       58.2582583
24       75.3753754
100     100.0000000
```

The second data frame is 10000 draws from a `runif` distribution, using the code:

```
 testData <- (runif(10000))*100
```

For each row in `testData`, I want to locate the corresponding `cumfreq` in `cumFreqDist` and add the corresponding `Time` value into a new column in `testData`. Because `testData` is a test data frame standing in for a real data frame, I do not wish to sort `testData`.

Because I am dealing with cumulative frequencies, if the `testData` value is `23.30...` the `Time` value that should be returned is `8`. That is, I need to locate the nearest `cumfreq` value that does not exceed the `testData` value, and return only that one value.

The `data.table` package has been mentioned for other similar questions, but my limited understanding is that this package requires a key to be identified in both data frames (after conversion to data tables) and I can't assume that the `testData` values meet the requirements for being assigned as a key - and it appears that assigning a key will sort the data. This will cause me issues when I set a seed later in further work I am doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) is perfect for this:

```
set.seed(1);
cumFreqDist <- data.frame(Time=c(0,4,6,8,12,16,18,20,24,100), cumfreq=c(0.0000000,0.9009009,1.8018018,7.5075075,23.4234234,39.6396396,53.4534535,58.2582583,75.3753754,100.0000000) );
testData <- data.frame(x=runif(10000)*100);
testData$Time <- cumFreqDist$Time[findInterval(testData$x,cumFreqDist$cumfreq)];
head(testData,20);
##            x Time
## 1  26.550866   12
## 2  37.212390   12
## 3  57.285336   18
## 4  90.820779   24
## 5  20.168193    8
## 6  89.838968   24
## 7  94.467527   24
## 8  66.079779   20
## 9  62.911404   20
## 10  6.178627    6
## 11 20.597457    8
## 12 17.655675    8
## 13 68.702285   20
## 14 38.410372   12
## 15 76.984142   24
## 16 49.769924   16
## 17 71.761851   20
## 18 99.190609   24
## 19 38.003518   12
## 20 77.744522   24
```